# Custom deserializer to resolve external type id for nested object in list

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given the following JSON:

```
{
    "parent": {
        "id": 0,
        "children": [{
            "child": {
                "id": 1,
                "description": "A",
                "parent": 0
                "events": [{
                    "onclick": {
                        "source": 1
                    }
                }],
            }
        }, {
            "grandchild": {
                "id": 2,
                "description": "B",
                "parent": 0
                "events": [{
                    "onclick": {
                        "source": 2
                    }
                }],
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I am attempting to deserialize the "onclick" events contained within the child nodes 1 (Child A) and 2 (Child B). The "source" field within onclick refers to the id of the onclick's child node.

JsonIdentityInfo's javadoc indicates that

> Object id has to be serialized as a property in case of POJOs; object identity is currently NOT support for JSON Array types (Java arrays or Lists) or Java Map types.

Which means I need a custom deserializer in order to create a Child object as the source of an OnClick object.

The problem I have is that "child" could be one of many possible objects (in the example, it could be "child" or "grandchild"). How, within my deserializer, could I find out what the source object's type is? Alternatively is there anyway I can include the Child/Grandchild name as a property within the onclick node?

EventMixIn:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = OnClick.class, name = "onclick")
})
public abstract class EventMixIn {

    @JsonProperty("source")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = SourceDeserializer.class)
    public abstract View getSource();

}
```

SourceDeserializer:

```
public class SourceDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<View> {

    public SourceDeserializer() {
        super(View.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        Long sourceId = parser.getCurrentName(Long.class);

        /*
         * TODO How to discover whether sourceId refers to a Child or
         * a Grandchild? Ideally have a means of retrieving the actual
         * Child/Grandchild object
         */
        return new Child(sourceId);
    }

}
```

I cannot call specific objects on ObjectMapper.readValue() because I am deserializing the Parent class, which contains both Child and Grandchild objects within it.